# Access SQL, different domain, same server (VPS)

Tags: sql, cross-domain

I have a VPS Server with WHM + cPanel. I have created two accounts in WHM, namely 'Domain A' and 'Domain B'. For reference:

Domain A: www.abc.com
Domain B: www.xyz.com

Say www.abc.com is a news website with all categories, a huge database, but completely not segmented as it has indeed all categories of news.

Now I have bought Domain B, www.xyz.com and I want it to be a news website aswell, but niche-focused, so it will have a completely different lay-out and design, but it will only have one news category. The news is ofcourse the same as www.abc.com, but once again it only has one category. Instead of having to add the same news on both sides (exactly the same, but please ignore SEO and everything else for a second). I want this site to use the database of www.abc.com, with a modified query (adding the condition of the category).

Is this possible, if so please tell me how.

Currently I am getting: 
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'legend'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/user/public_html/index.php on line 19.

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/user/public_html/index.php on line 19.

Note: The first thing in index.php is a connection to the sql database. Visiting the /mysql.php returns an echo of successfull connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use add-on domains which adds the additional domain on the same cPanel account.

Or you can try the database user method by granting the user from another cPanel account the rights to access the database (I haven't tested this) http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/mysql-access-between-cpanel-accounts-126409.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am aware that add-on might indeed be the best solution. However, it is inefficient in the end, because I might want to make tens of niche-category websites. 

I just read through that article/forum discussion but it does not offer the solution. I have SSH access, however what I want is: 1x WHM Account, 2x List Account, both have their own cPanel and environment for PHPmyadmin/SQL and can not see each others data at all. I want Account B to be able to access the database of Account A. Hope this clarifies what I want.

Comment: Maybe you can look into remote mysql access: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/RemoteMySQL